# Random Turtle Walk

Tags: python, random, module, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want to make a program where the turtle walks off randomly in any direction with different colors, I can write the code to make the turtle move but I can't figure out how to randomly generate the different color list.

Comment: You can use this library called [Random](https://www.w3schools.com/python/module_random.asp). [Here](https://www.pythonpool.com/python-random-color/) is brilliant page that helps you to generate random colors in `Python` using the `Random` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't figure out how to randomly generate the different color list.

By default, Python turtle uses an RGB color system with a triplet of floating point red, green and blue values ranging from 0.0 to 1.0

These values are the same as what the `random()` function in the **random.py** module generates, so random color can be as simple as:

```
import turtle
from random import random

turtle.color(random(), random(), random())
```

Here's a silly example that does just that:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import random

RADIUS = 200

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.shape('turtle')
turtle.shapesize(5, outline=5)
turtle.speed('fast')
turtle.width(90)

turtle.penup()
turtle.sety(-RADIUS)
turtle.pendown()

def randomize():
    turtle.pencolor(random(), random(), random())
    turtle.fillcolor(random(), random(), random())

    turtle.circle(RADIUS, extent=30)

    screen.ontimer(randomize)

randomize()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Note that a turtle has *two* colors, a *pen* color and a *fill* color.

Comment: ok but should I give my code a random list of colors to pick from or just by writing random it will generate the colors by himself?

Comment: @Zainab, you can do either -- it's *your* program!